# Is Scheduled Backup Work When Manual Backup is Running

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

If i scheduled differential backup for every one hour and suppose i take full backup at 6.59pm, Will the schedule backup work or not ?

Any help please if possible with reason ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it should work

If the full backup @ 6 59 doesnt finish by the time 7 pm differential backup starts then the diff backup should backup everything since 6 pm( the last diff backup)